# How To Remove Lines Containing Any Accents letters-characters in notepad++ or Emeditor

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing, editing

Full example file containing:

```
ÁáÀàÂâǍǎĂăÃãẢảẠạÄäÅåĀāĄąẤấẦầẪẫẨẩẬậẮắẰằẴẵẲẳẶặǺǻ
ĆćĈĉČčĊċÇçĎďĐđÐÉéÈèÊêĚěĔĕẼẽẺẻĖėËëĒēĘęẾếỀềỄễỂểẸ
ẹỆệĞğĜĝĠġĢģĤĥĦħÍíÌìĬĭÎîǏǐÏïĨĩĮįĪīỈỉỊịĴĵĶķĹĺĽľĻ
ļŁłĿŀŃńŇňÑñŅņÓóÒòŎŏÔôỐốỒồỖỗỔổǑǒÖöŐőÕõØøǾǿŌōỎỏƠ
ơỚớỜờỠỡỞởỢợỌọỘộṔṕṖṗŔŕŘřŖŗŚśŜŝŠšŞşŤťŢţŦŧÚúÙùŬŭÛ
ûǓǔŮůÜüǗǘǛǜǙǚǕǖŰűŨũŲųŪūỦủƯưỨứỪừỮữỬửỰựỤụẂẃẀẁŴŵẄ
ẅÝýỲỳŶŷŸÿỸỹỶỷỴỵŹźŽžŻż€æûùàâéèêëïîôœ
```

Needed result:

```
Remove Any Lines Contaning What look like or Described Above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ has no easy way to *search* for these kind of characters, let alone *replace entire lines* containing them.

For this solution, I'm assuming the characters you want to be gone are in these [Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block): Latin-1 Supplement, Latin Extended-A and Latin Extended-B. The first accented letter in the first block is `À`; the last one from the last block is `ɏ`. That means the [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `[À-ɏ]` matches all characters you're interested in.

- Step 1: open the Find dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and select the Mark tab. Specify Find what ...: the regular expression `[À-ɏ]`. Make sure the Search Mode is set to Regular Expression and click the 'Mark All' button.

  [image]

  This will 'mark' all lines you want to delete.
- Step 2: menu Search -> Bookmark -> Remove Bookmarked Lines.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To delete all the characters you don't need in Notepad++ is to replace them with none.

You can add all the characters at once in the replace menu and divide these with a sumbol: | 

1. From the menu Search --> Replace (or Ctrl + H) 
2. Find what --> ẹ|Ệ|ệ|Ğ|ğ|Ĝ|ĝ|Ġ|ġ|Ģ|ř|Ŗ|ŗ|Ś|ś|Ŝ|ŝ and so on 
3. Replace with --> leave it blank 
4. Replace all

Comment: That will only replace the characters themselves, not the entire lines.